# Deleted Ubuntu from dual boot system, now can't boot into Windows

Tags: dual-boot, grubrescue, gnu

Can't boot into Windows after Ubuntu partition was deleted. [Fixmbr](https://pureinfotech.com/repair-master-boot-record-mbr-windows-10/) did not solve the problem. Cannot figure out what the actual problem is.

Comment: Problem: Deleted GRUB when Ubuntu Partition was deleted. GRUB was the Ubuntu app which gave you the choice of booting Ubuntu Linux or choosing to boot from the Windows Boot Manager. See https://pureinfotech.com/repair-master-boot-record-mbr-windows-10/

Comment: I have tried all those commands but still doesnt work i dont know how to fix it now :(

Comment: No Ubuntu means the problem is not with Ubuntu.... makes it off topic. Your solution should be within the Windows installation media. So you should ask windows users.

Comment: Thanks man it actually works. U solved my biggest problem i was facing since a week. GOD bless you!

Answer (score 0):

When your computer boots try constantly pressing F11 Del F1 and try to reach boot options, even better if you can reach boot options in the BIOS.  You'll need to google what the buttons to press for your computer make and model if those keys I recommended don't work.  You'll need to constantly be jabbing them soon as you press the power button.  Then you should be able to pick Windows Boot Loader or UEFI type options.

Answer (score 0):

(If I were u)I would try the [Trinity rescue kit](http://trinityhome.org/) has options to repair booting [here](http://trinityhome.org/Home/index.php?content=3.4_BOOTSECTOR_REPAIR_1)

Another shot would be to actually reinstall Ubuntu on that partition which would probably reinstall grub but then you can run the [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) which is a utility, can also be run as a live cd.

Also take a look at [reFind](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/)